# Что это значит "sc, is и os - объяви пабличные, там, где нужно, и соответственного типа."

Tags: java, android-studio

Нашёл пример кода и я не пойму что мне нужно сделать с: "sc,is и os" чтобы было всё верно

Коннект:

```
try{
    sc = new Socket("айпишник", Integer.parseInt("порт"));
    sc.setKeepAlive(true);
    is = sc.getInputStream();
    os = sc.getOutputStream();
    ///System.out.println("Connected!");
}catch(Exception x)
```

Чтение:

```
while (is.available()==0)
            {
                try{Thread.sleep(50);
                }catch (Exception cc){
                }
            }
            byte[] baray= new byte[1024];
            is.read(baray, 0, is.available());
```

Запись:

```
os.write("строчка".getBytes());
```

sc, is и os - объяви пабличные, там, где нужно, и соответственного типа. Удачи.

```
    Socket sc;
InputStream is;
OutputStream os;

    try{
    sc = new Socket("192.168.1.23", Integer.parseInt("8080"));
    sc.setKeepAlive(true);
    is = sc.getInputStream();
    os = sc.getOutputStream();
    ///System.out.println("Connected!");
}catch(Exception x)
{


}
```

Comment: кому вы предлагаете объявлять пабличные и желаете удачи? так же неплохо объяснить, в чем именно ваша проблема так, чтобы людям, далеким от некоторого обрывка диалога тоже было понятно, в чем именно требуется удача - этот код не работает, вы не знаете, как бы могли его использовать или что ..

Comment: Если даже вы не понимаете, что вам нужно, то мы тем более понять не можем. Разве что могу посоветовать для начала почитать какие-то книжки по Java, для начинающих.

Comment: Это пример сообщение которое было написано на сайте, проблема в том что я не знаю как нужно объявить sc,is и os

Answer (score 1):

Ну можете их так объявить:

```
Socket sc;
InputStream is;
OutputStream os;
try{
    sc = new Socket("айпишник", Integer.parseInt("порт"));
    sc.setKeepAlive(true);
    is = sc.getInputStream();
    os = sc.getOutputStream();
    ///System.out.println("Connected!");
}catch(Exception x) {}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88145/discussion-on-answer-by-komdosh----sc-is--os--).